# Is it possible to use the Proxy authentication toward an External authenticated user?

Tags: oracle, authentication

Suppose I have three user A, B, C, the three of them defined as External Authenticated (there are three OS users on the same machine).

Now think about a WS that usually get USER/PASS information from the client (where A, B, and C are) and connect to the Database impersonating A, B, and C. In this scenario that wouldn't work, since the WS is on another machine, and A, B, and C cannot provide passwords for the db connection.

I was thinking about creating a user D, not external authenticated, and grante the proxy authentication to D so that he's able to connect as A, B, and C. Would that work?

Would I simply need to run the following?

```
ALTER USER D GRANT CONNECT THROUGH A
ALTER USER D GRANT CONNECT THROUGH B
ALTER USER D GRANT CONNECT THROUGH C
```

And how do I implement the connection from the WS? I just need to feed the Username?

Answer (score 0):

It turn out it is possible but it must be done the other way around. You alter user A, B, C to grant connect through D, that will allow you to connect as A when you are D, just by having A username.

The only thing to remember is that OS authenticated user have the username OSP$USERNAME